# No sound anymore on Lubuntu 14.04.3, Kernel 3.13.0-63

Tags: 14.04, sound, kernel, lubuntu

The current version of Lubuntu (kernel 3.13.0-63 in use now) produces no sound anymore. Neither Audacious, Gnome player, YouTube or CD player produce sound. My installation CD (Lubuntu distribution 14.04 LTS and kernel 13.0-24) works fine and no changes in either hardware (SB Live!EMU10k1 rev0.7) or software (still same native applications) have occurred! In both cases (boot from CD and from HD) the SB PCI card is recognized as PCI device with "System Profiler & Benchmark".
I don't know from what version this issue has started because the "mute" was set for about 6 months. So probably the "mute" was active during updates. May this is causing the problem?
How to solve it? Many thanks in advance, grtz AlbertJohn

Comment: maybe see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1671273, if you have firefox 52